# How to open a Model Dialog Box inside another Modal Dialog Box in Google Scripts

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am brand new to google scripts and currently I have a modal dialog box that opens an html file into the picture below.
[image]

I would like to able to press the open dashboard button and close this box and open another modal dialog box, however I am struggling to figure out how. Unlike normal html, I can't use a href to reference my other html file for some reason. I have also tried closing the modal box and then  recalling the GS function that opens the initial dialog box, but with the new html passed in, also to no avail. I assume I am missing something simple here, since this is so trivial normally, but am not sure what I am missing, any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Code.gs

```
    function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Jigs & Tools')
      .addItem('First item', 'displayHtmlViewer')
      .addToUi();
}

function include(filename) {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
        .getContent();
}

function displayHtmlViewer(file = "index"){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file)
            .evaluate()
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'J&T Dashboard');
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!=include('stylesheet');?>
  </head>
  
  <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    
    <div class="btnGroup2" style="width:100%">
      <button style="width:50%" button onclick="google.script.host.close() ; google.script.run.displayHtmlViewer('dashboard')">Open dashboard</button>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"/></div>

    <div class="btnGroup1" style="width:100%">
      <button style="width:50%">Future Button 1</button>
      <button style="width:50%">Future Button 2</button>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"/> </div>


    <div class="btnGroup1" style="width:100%">
      <button style="width:50%">Future Button 3</button>
      <button style="width:50%">Future Button 4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"/> </div>


    <div class="btnGroup1" style="width:100%">
      <button style="width:50%">Future Button 5</button>
      <button style="width:50%">Future Button 6</button>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"/> </div>

    <div class="btnGroup2" style="width:100%" id=myBtn>
      <button style="width:50%" button onclick="google.script.host.close()"> Exit </button>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
 <body>
<h4>This is the Dashboard</h4>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the dialog is opened under a dialog that has already been opened, the existing dialog is closed. I thought that this might be able to be used for your situation. In your script, `google.script.host.close()` closes the dialog. By this, `google.script.run.displayHtmlViewer('dashboard')` is not run. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
<button style="width:50%" button onclick="google.script.host.close() ; google.script.run.displayHtmlViewer('dashboard')">Open dashboard</button>
```

#### To:

```
<button style="width:50%" button onclick="google.script.run.displayHtmlViewer('dashboard')">Open dashboard</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was my original solution, also to no avail, which makes me think Im missing something somewhere else.

Comment: @RichardGeef Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill and poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Unfortunately, this was my original solution, also to no avail, which makes me think Im missing something somewhere else.`, I couldn't understand your situation. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I have already tried to use your answer 
<button style="width:50%" button onclick="google.script.run.displayHtmlViewer('dashboard')">Open dashboard</button>
 But it did not work.

Comment: @RichardGeef Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `I have already tried to use your answer <button style="width:50%" button onclick="google.script.run.displayHtmlViewer('dashboard')">Open dashboard</button> But it did not work.`, when I tested your script, the dialog is changed from 1st one to `dashboard.html`. So I proposed it. If you can do, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your script in your question for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Here is a link to a copy of what I am using, the spreadsheet is blank, there is only code. Maybe I am missing some sort of add on to make this work if you say it works for you.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TGdUiX7_1WCvPv41PvYwzBVZVSzBLrK79S-qkf4HElw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RichardGeef Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I couldn't open your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, should be able to be openable/editable now. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TGdUiX7_1WCvPv41PvYwzBVZVSzBLrK79S-qkf4HElw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RichardGeef Thank you for replying. I could open your sample Spreadsheet. Although I'm not sure about the detail of `But it did not work.`, when I tested your script including my suggested modification on your sample Spreadsheet, I confirmed that when I click the button of "Open dashboard", the HTML of `This is the Dashboard` is shown. I apologize for this.

Comment: Strange, when I open the same spreadsheet I sent you, it does not work for me. I'm not sure what the problem could be, but thanks for the advise. I guess the problem must be something on my computer.

Comment: @RichardGeef Thank you for replying. I cannot replicate your situation of `Strange, when I open the same spreadsheet I sent you, it does not work for me.`. When I tested your sample Spreadsheet, it works fine. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For example, what browser are you using? I tested it using Chrome. How about this?

Comment: Well this was the problem, thank you. I was using Chrome and it did not work. I switched to Firefox and it does work. I guess the problem must be with one of my Chrome extensions. Thank you so much for your help. I knew the solution would be simple.

Comment: @RichardGeef Thank you for replying. I could understand the situation. Thank you, too.